# Example of "not" a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, formal-power-series

I read the following statement in an article:

Suppose $(a_k) $ is a nonnegative sequence and let $a(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$. If $a(x)$ is not a power series in $x^t$ for any integer $t>1$, then....

But, I am confused with "not a power series". Does anyone please give me an example of this? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The phrase is "not a power series in $x^t$". That is, $a(x)$ cannot be written in the form $\sum_{m=0}^\infty b_m (x^t)^m$, for $t>1$. Contrast, for instance, the power series for $\cos(x)$; the each term has an even power of $x$, so that series *can* be written a power series in $x^2$.

Comment: The emphasis is on the integer $t$ being larger than $1$. I.e., $\cos(x)$ is a power series in terms of $x^2$, but $\sin(x)$ is not.

Comment: Ignore my comments, I missed the point of the question.

Comment: It means $\gcd ( \{ k | a_k \neq 0 \}) $ is one.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Now it's clear.